# Building a Summary-of-Projects sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive, google-apps-script

I am trying to build a `Summary Sheet`, which imports data from `Project Sheet`s as they are created and updated. The `Summary Sheet` is stored in a team drive, and the `Project Sheet`s are stored in a separate folder in that team drive. Each new project will have its own sheet, which is created when the project is accepted according to a template.

The folder for `Project Sheet`s will end up with many sheets, for example:

```
01112016
02112016
15112016
12122016
```

The `Summary Sheet` then needs to IMPORTRANGE data from these sheets as they are created and updated.

```
SummarySheet
Project 01112016, Date1, Date2, Sum1, Average1
Project 02112016, Date1, Date2, empty, empty
Project 15112016, Date1, empty, empty, empty
Project 12122016, empty, empty, empty, empty
empty
```

I had tried building this in Excel, but the indirect function doesn't pull data from closed workbooks. In Google Sheets I have a different problem, the addresses of future sheets are unknown, because each new sheet address is unpredictable (as far as I know). There may be a thousand project sheets created each year, so automating the `Summary Sheet` is important.

Any ideas how to predict new sheet addresses, or to identify sheets in the folder of a team drive, in order to link `Project Sheet`s and `Summary Sheet`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFiles()) from the Class Folder of [Google Apps Script Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/).

Related questions on SO (include scripts)

- [List all files id inside a folder (no subfolders)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25360214/1595451)
- [Google Drive - How to List all Files in a specified folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30428074/1595451)